# Autoscaling not working in Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, deployment, autoscaling

I searched many blogs, docs and tutos but not able to fix this issue.

In the deployment.yml

```
  resources:
    requests:
       memory: 64Mi
       cpu: 128m
    limits:
       memory: 128Mi
       cpu: 256m
```

for autoscaling.yml file:

```
 apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
 kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
 metadata:
    name: dotnetapi
    namespace: default
 spec:
   scaleTargetRef:
      apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
      kind: Deployment
      name: dotnetapi
   minReplicas: 1
   maxReplicas: 7
   targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: kubernetes version is 1.9.6

Comment: Hi, Can you check weather heapster or metric server is running in kube-system namespace? HPA get its data for decision from these components.

Comment: yes, heapster is running under kube-system namespace

Comment: Well, the errors say, It could not find the pod. can you verify the pod is up and running?  the configurations seems fine to me